# How to filter empty nodes via dom?

Tags: php, dom

I want to **get only elements** which have **some real text** or **child element nodes** in it (not spaces or `&nbsp;` etc).

I tried the following html :

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

And i have tried so far this code :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$i = 0;
while (is_object($html_synch = $dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item($i))) {
    foreach ($html_synch->childNodes as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeName != "script" && $node->nodeName != "style" &&
                XML_COMMENT_NODE != $node->nodeType):
            get_children($node);
        endif;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

And then in get_children function I am using this code to filter the empty nodes or nodes with `&nbsp;` :

```
foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) :
    if (trim($child->nodeValue) != ""):
        echo $child->nodeValue;  // it returns Â
        echo $child->nodeName;   // it returns #text
        array_push($children_type, $child->nodeType);
    endif;
endforeach;
print_r($children_type);
```

It returns `#text Â and Array ( [0] => 3 )` for only `<p>&nbsp;</p>`. So how can i filter them? And I do know that #text is special node name for text.

**[Link to demo :](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d0ee6ef92a28651bf577299b3f39c0506ae9261)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some explanation beforehand: The reason, you are seeing À is that your HTML document is treated as UTF-8 but you are displaying it as ISO 8859-1. The non-breaking space `&nbsp;` is encoded as two bytes in UTF-8: `0xC2 0xA0`. In ISO 8859-1 it's just `0xA0`, while `0xC2` means `À`

Now, you can specify in `trim()`, which characters should be trimmed, so you can include the non-breaking space (the default characters have to be added explicitly, too):

```
if (trim($child->nodeValue, " \n\r\t\0\xC2\xA0") !== ""):
    // value is not empty
```

At the moment your function does no *filtering*, so I am not sure, what exactly you want to do with these items. But the rest should be easy, for example:

- count children whose node type is not text **or** value is not empty
- if count > 0, keep element

### Update

The rest of your code is a bit crude, so I made a minimum working example:

**Test code:**

```
$html = <<<HTML
<body>
 <div>
  <p>not-empty</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
</body>
HTML;


$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//*') as $node) {
  if (!count($node->childNodes) || trim($node->nodeValue, " \n\r\t\0\xC2\xA0")==='') {
    echo 'to filter: ' . $node->getNodePath() . "\n";
  }
}
```

**Test output:**

```
to filter: /html/body/div/p[2]
to filter: /html/body/div/div
```

**[Link to demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/343cc0e26b3dee2cf2a176f8e21e4aec81fad731)**

Comment: then you are doing something else wrong. Have a look at my update.

Comment: can you kindly have a look at this code please? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a352b78ec734bd7770542871fb119224127b0106

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d0ee6ef92a28651bf577299b3f39c0506ae9261 check it now

Comment: In line 12, replace $node with $child (twice).

Comment: Thanks fab :) it really helped alot